# Sum of two polynomials with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to addition of two polynomial in python with arrays. But when the polynomials have different size, i cant get it. so how can i do to addition of two different size polynomial in python with arrays?

```
def addPoly(PolyOne, PolyTwo):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(PolyOne)):
        for j in range(len(PolyTwo)):
            if PolyOne[i][1] == PolyTwo[j][1]:
              equalResult = PolyOne[i][0] + PolyTwo[j][0]
              if equalResult != 0:
                result.append((equalResult, PolyOne[i][1]))

    for i in range(len(PolyOne)):
        if result[i][1] != PolyOne[i][1]:
            result.append(PolyOne[i])
    for i in range(len(PolyOne)):
        if result[i][1] != PolyTwo[i][1]:
            result.append(PolyTwo[i])
    return result

print(addPoly([(4,3),(8,1),(3,0),(8,9)],[(4,3),(2,1), (8,7),(6,0),(23,31)]))
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(addPoly([(4,3),(8,1),(3,0),(8,9)],[(4,3),(2,1), (8,7),(6,0),(23,31)]))
  File "main.py", line 11, in addPoly
    if result[i][1] != PolyOne[i][1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[(4,3),(8,1),(3,0),(8,9)] => 4x^3 + 8x^1 + 3x^0 + 8x^9 p1 polynomial

[(4,3),(2,1), (8,7),(6,0),(23,31)] => 4x^3 + 2x^1 + 6x^0 + 8x^9 + 8x^7 + 23x^31 P2 polynomial

output should be : p1 + p2 = [(8,3),(10,1),(9,0),(8,9),(8.7),(23,31)] => 8x^3 + 10x^1 + 9x^0 + 8x^9 + 8x^7 + 23x^31 result polynomial

Comment: `len(x)` is an int. The `zip` function takes iterables.

Comment: This is much simpler if you use a `dict` to map an exponent to a coefficient.

Comment: @chepner this is an homework, I have to do this with a list

Comment: You may have to accept lists as input, but you can convert them to dicts for calculating the answer.

Comment: @jarmod I updated the code. Can you look again?

Comment: @chepner Do you have a code block you made as an example?

Comment: How, exactly, are these polynomials being represented int these "arrays"? What do the pairs of number mean?

Comment: @martineau [(4,3),(8,1),(3,0),(8,9)] => 4x^3 + 8x^1 + 3x^0 + 8x^9 p1 polynomial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group together the values for all exponents (and sum them):

```
def add_poly(*args):
    expval = sorted([(e, v) for poly in args for v, e in poly])
    return [
        (sum(v for _, v in g), e)
        for e, g in groupby(expval, key=lambda kv: kv[0])
    ]
```

Test:

```
>>> add_poly(
    [(4,3),(8,1),(3,0),(8,9)],
    [(4,3),(2,1),(8,7),(6,0),(23,31)],
)
[(9, 0), (10, 1), (8, 3), (8, 7), (8, 9), (23, 31)]
```

Explanation:

- using `*args` provides us a way to give any number (even 0) polynomials to add, not just 2. E.g., try: `add_poly()`, `add_poly([(1,1)])`. As usual in Python, `args` then contains the list of arguments, i.e., of polynomials.
- `expval` contains the flatten list of (reversed tuples) `(exponent, value)` from all polynomials. The list is sorted (as tuples, therefore by `exponent` and then `value`, bringing all same exponents together) in preparation for `groupby()`. For example, given a single polynomial `[(10,1),(20,2),(1,0)]`, it would contain `[(0,1),(1,10),(2,20)]`.
- `groupby`: make sure to read the docs linked above. The key we use for the grouping is the exponent: for a given tuple, use the first value (which, in `expval`, is the exponent). Basically it creates an iterator of tuples: `(key, group)`, where `key` is an exponent, and `group` is an iterator of all tuples with that exponent.
- for each such `(e, g)` tuple, we keep `e` and we sum all values in the group `g`. We bring the order back to what you define as polynomials which is a list of `(value, exponent)` tuples.

Notes:

- You didn't define explicitly how your polynomials were represented. It is only from your example that I inferred your representation to be `[(coeff_0, exponent_0), (coeff_1, exponent_1), ...]`. One neat thing that Python provides is called `namedtuple`. You could declare terms as `term = namedtuple('term', 'coeff exponent')`. Your terms would still be tuples, but they would clearly indicate which element is the coefficient and which is the exponent. You could even redefine its `__str__(self)` method to return `f'{self.coeff} * x^{self.exponent}'` or something of your choice.
- See also [`numpy.poly1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) that has some interesting abilities, such as evaluation, addition (with other polynomials) and `__str__`.
- You may also look at [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#polynomial-rational-function-simplification) for more powerful handling of symbolic expressions.

Comment: thanks a lot but can you explain the code more? cuz i have to explain this to professor. I can't understand what it do line by line.

Comment: I added an explanation and some notes. I would suggest for you to add some `print` (or better, use a debugger) and some test examples to see for yourself what the various parts are and what the operations do. You could also make the function less compact and split every line into several steps, so that you can inspect each step. Of course, I would highly recommend for you to read the docs of `groupby` and play with it, so that you have a very good understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, all polynomials have the same size: they have an (countably) infinite number of terms, one per allowed exponent. In practice, most of those exponents have 0 as their coefficient, so we ignore them.

To compute the sum, convert your list of exponent/coefficient pairs to a dict that lets us look up a coefficient (given an exponent) in constant time.

```
p1 = dict([(4,3),(8,1),(3,0),(8,9)])
p2 = dict([(4,3),(2,1), (8,7),(6,0),(23,31)])
```

Now, we simply need to iterate over all the explicitly represented exponents (if it's missing from both, we can assume the coefficient is 0 in both).

```
from itertools import chain

answer = dict()
for exponent in chain(p1, p2):
    answer[exponent] = p1.get(exponent, 0) + p2.get(exponent, 0)
```

We use `get` instead of `p1[exponent]` so that we can get the implied 0 as the coefficient for a missing exponent.

Once you have `answer`, you can convert it pack to a list of exponent/coefficient pairs using

```
result = list(answer.items())
```

I leave it as an exercise to implement `addPoly` using this idea.

Comment: I tested this, but unfortunately I did not get the output I mentioned above